# ImageView animations in live wallpaper

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout, wallpaper, android-framelayout

(Android)
I am working on adapting a full-screen analog clock app to a live wallpaper.
The app use three separate `ImageView` for hour, min, sec hands and `RotateAnimation`.

I have been looking around for a method to use ImageView in live wallpaper. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174723/using-layout-resources-in-a-livewallpaper-on-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442577/using-a-framelayout-as-a-live-wallpaper?lq=1) indicates that this should be possible with `measure()` and `layout()`, but I
don't really know how to use it.
For example, I use the code below to load `clock_background.png` into a `ImageView`.

```
public class MyWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {
    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new MyWallpaperEngine();
    }
    ....
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
        mContext = getBaseContext();
        backgroundImage = new ImageView(mContext);
        backgroundImage.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_background));
    }
}
```

Later I have:

```
backgroundImage.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
backgroundImage.layout(0, 0, 150, 150);
```

I expect the code above would display `clock_background.png` in the upper-left corner of
the screen. I tried to put the two lines above in `OnSurfaceCreated` and `OnSurfaceChanged`. Unfortunately it does not work.
As I understand, live wallpaper gives a Surface (not SurfaceView), from which one can get
canvas and draw things on it.
I apologise for being very new at Android: Am I doing it all wrong? I just don't want to
mess with `drawBitmap` or likes, and I don't care about battery anyway.
Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I short, yes you're doing it wrong.
Use the supplied canvas and its drawX() methods

Comment: Thanks! but I am looking for a way to avoid canvas and draw..(). And as I mentioned that way does exist, though may not preferred.

Comment: It would be useful when referring someone to a different method to provide some direction how to use it for the desired results.